# Storing info in an arraylist that is the value in a hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, store

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.AbstractMap;

/**
 * A simple model of a mail server. The server is able to receive
 * mail items for storage, and deliver them to clients on demand.
 */
 public class MailServer
 {
    // Storage for the arbitrary number of mail items to be stored
    // on the server.
    private HashMap<String,ArrayList<MailItem>> mailMap;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public MailServer()
    {
        mailMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<MailItem>>();
    }

    /**
     * Return how many mail items are waiting for a user.
     */
    public int howManyMailItems(String who)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(ArrayList<MailItem> array : mailMap.values()) {
            for (MailItem item : array) {
                if (item.getTo().equals(who)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    //  public int howManyMailItems(String who) 
    //  {    
    //      return mailMap.get(who).size(); 
    //  }

    /**
     * Return the next mail item for a user or null if there
     * are none.
     */
    public MailItem getNextMailItems(String who, int howMany)
    {
        // Access the ArrayList for "who" remove and return the first element
        // Be careful what if "who" doesn't have an entry in the mailMap
        // Or what if "who" doesn't have any mail?
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MailItem>>> it = 
        mailMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MailItem>> entry = it.next();
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<MailItem> value = entry.getValue();
            if (key.equals(who));
            {
                return value.remove(0);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Add the given mail item to the message list.
     */
    public void post(String who)
    {
        if (mailMap.containsKey(who)) {
            Map.put(who, Map.get(who) + 1);
        }

    }
}
```

The above code is for a basic mail server. I was attempting to make it store a MailItem(String recipient, String subject, String message) in a HashMap with a String key and an ArrayList (of MailItems) value.

What I am having trouble with is the post() method. I can't figure out how to make it take the parameter of who the message is intended for and store it in the corresponding ArrayList.

I am also having problems with the getNextMailItems() method. I can't figure out how to make it return multiple items from the ArrayList of the recipient. All I have been able to figure out is to add a parameter specifying how many MailItems to return.

I am incredibly inexperienced with java and am still learning. Please help. Thank you all.

Comment: I recommend looking at the Guava [Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps) which replaces the map of lists with a more intuitive and robust implementation.

Comment: The project I am doing requires a HashMap with an ArrayList

Comment: It is but I am not trying to cheat. I just don't have any help available to me right now. Stack overflow was suggested to me as a good way to find help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are learning Java, let me point out a few things:

- Please try the Guava [`MultiMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) instead of the much uglier:

  ```
  private HashMap<String,ArrayList<MailItem>> mailMap;
  ```

  Also try to use interfaces instead of classes, i.e., `Map<String,List<MailItem>` would be better because it does not tie you to the particular implementation.
- This is not optimal and I suspect wrong:

  ```
  int count = 0;
  for(ArrayList<MailItem> array : mailMap.values()) {
    for (MailItem item : array) {
      if (item.getTo().equals(who)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  you should call `get(who)` on the map and if you get a non null list, you will have a list of `MailItem`s for `who`. Then calling `List.size()` will give you the count (I suspect) you need.
- Two notes about this block of code:

  ```
  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MailItem>>> it = mailMap.entrySet().iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MailItem>> entry = it.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    ArrayList<MailItem> value = entry.getValue();
    if (key.equals(who)); // the semicolon here means that if the condition is true, do nothing
    {
      return value.remove(0); // this block is ALWAYS EXECUTED
    }
  }
  return null;
  ```

  If the condition in the if is true, nothing will be executed because of the semicolon and the code in the code block will **always** be executed the **first** time. That said, once again you are given the key, so you don't need to loop through the whole map (see previous point). However, if you want to iterate a map please use the more compact idiom:

  ```
  for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<MailItem>> e : mailMap.entrySet()){
    // do something with the key and value, e.getKey(), e.getValue()
  }
  ```
- Finally, this block is puzzling:

  ```
  if (mailMap.containsKey(who)) {
    Map.put(who, Map.get(who) + 1);
  }
  ```

  what are you trying to do? Map is the name of an interface and doesn't have static methods `put` or `get` so that won't even compile. If you were trying to add an element to `mailMap`  for the key `who` then you probably want something like (typical idiom for map of lists, again see [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) for a better API):

  ```
  ArrayList<MailItem> l = mailMap.get(who);
  if(l == null){ // this super verbose code will simplify with the Guava MultiMap
    l = new ArrayList<MailItem>();
    mailMap.put(who, l);
  }
  l.add(/* code to create a new MailItem */);
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I think i understand and will try the suggested bits of code.